# As internal energy is extensive property for all of the gases, then how is the internal energy for ideal gas independent of change in volume?

Tags: thermodynamics

I read that internal energy for an ideal gas is independent of change in volume, but internal energy is an extensive property both are contradictory, please explain.

Comment: They are not contradictory. Internal energy is proportional to $N$ (number of particles), so it is indeed extensive.

Answer (score 1):

An extensive property satisfies the following criterion: if we take system 1 with $U$ internal energy and put it next to another copy of system 1, also with $U$ internal energy, then the total internal energy of the composite system is $2U$.

(In contrast, an intensive property such as temperature doesn't satisfy this criterion; if two identical systems with temperature $T$ are joined, then it's unusual to talk about the "total" temperature; instead, there's a uniform temperature, which remains $T$.)

When people talk about the internal energy for "an ideal gas" being independent of a change in volume, they really mean "*a certain quantity* of an ideal gas". Doubling the volume without changing the mass of an ideal gas, for example, isn't equivalent to joining two systems, which would double the volume, the mass, and the energy, among other extensive parameters.